# Вставка значений переменных в текст Javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеется текст нескольких различных математических задач.

Например: "За 2 часа турист прошел 10 км, Какое расстояние пройдет турист за 3,5 часа."

Мне примерно нужно следующее, в одном текстовом файле имеется текст этих задач, мы случайным образом выбираем одну из них и вставляем случайные числа, после чего выводим его на страницу. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Вы используете nodeJS или же обычный js прикрепленный к html-странице?

Comment: Я могу для облегчения задачи сделать вот что: задачи не в одном текстовом файле хранить в папке "Задачи", в которой 1 текстовый файл - 1 задача. Так будет и ориентироваться в них проще в будущем, и решение вашей задачи будет прощи.

Comment: Использую обычный js. Как вариант, одна задача - один файл, тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

В файле с задачами числа надо заменить на уникальные идентификаторы
Например: За [X] часа турист [X]  км, Какое расстояние пройдет турист за [X] часа?
А потом в самом скрипте заменить идентификаторы на рандомные значения